# How do you sort a multiple column query (BY WEIGHT NOT ORDER) in an SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

To keep the question simple I'm going to give much simpler and abstract code than the actual SQL query.

At the moment I'm running two queries. The first is to get the MAX value of different SQL fields. For example... if `table.likes` is a column that we want to influence the order of the final results I'd get the max value `MAX(table.likes) AS max_likes` then get the ratio of each row to the max value.

```
(table.likes / max_table.max_likes) AS like_ratio
(table.comments / max_table.max_comments) AS comment_ratio
```

This gives me a nice range of [0, 1]. Then I can increase or decrease the importance of each row by including a scale: .3 for `like_ratio` and .2 for `comment_ratio`. So `like_ratio` becomes [.7, 1] and `comment_ratio` becomes [.8, 1].

```
((like_ratio * .3) + .7) * ((comment_ratio * .2) + .8) AS final_weight
```

This seems to work moderately well but I'm wondering if there's a better way to weigh multiple columns in the final result with MySQL as a sorting field. Sorting with comma separated values obviously doesn't work well because the same number of `table.likes` doesn't occur often and neglects the other columns like `table.comments`. I don't really like having to run one query to find all the max values then run the same query again to sort the values based off the `max_table`.

I've played around with the idea of using `ATAN(table.likes)` so that as `table.likes` increases, the weight gets closer and closer to 1. This doesn't seem to be ideal because anything past a certain threshold will become increasingly similar in value.

**Is there a "meta" to how you should sort if multiple columns are important to the final sort order?**

EDIT: EXAMPLE DATA

```
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|   |   likes    |   comments  | relevance       |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1 | 6          | 1           | 40              |
| 2 | 2          | 12          | 37              |
| 3 | 12         | 24          | 12              |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

First I select `MAX(table.likes)`: 12, `MAX(table.comments)`: 24, `MAX(table.query_relevance)`: 40.

```
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|   | max_likes  |max_comments |   max_relevance |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1 | 12         | 24          | 40              |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Next I get the ratio of each row to it's relevant maximum.  `likes / max_likes`: 6/12, `likes / max_likes`: 2/12, `likes / max_likes`: 12/12. The like for each column.

```
+---+------------+--------------+-----------------+
|   |like_weight |comment_weight| relevance_weight|
+---+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1 | .5         | .04          | 1               |
+---+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2 | .16        | .5           | .92             |
+---+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 3 | 1          | 1            | .3              |
+---+------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Next, I apply some sort of scale to each field so that different fields have different weights.

```
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
|   |like_weight  |comment_weight| relevance_weight|
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1 |.5 * .3 + .7 | .04 * .2 + .8| 1 * .4 + .6     |
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2 |.16 * .3 + .7| .5 * .2 + .8 | .92 * .4 + .6   |
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 3 | 1 * .3 + .7 | 1 * .2 + .8  | .3 * .4 + .6    |
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+

+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
|   |like_weight  |comment_weight| relevance_weight|
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1 |.85          | .808         | 1               |
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2 |.748         | .9           | .968            |
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 3 | 1           | 1            | .72             |
+---+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Finally I multiply all these values together to get a final sort column...

```
+---+------------+
|   |final_weight|
+---+------------+
| 1 | .6868      |
+---+------------+
| 2 | .6516      |
+---+------------+
| 3 | .72        |
+---+------------+
```

Comment: John, I have some ideas. But will help if you show us some sample data and what result you expect. Otherwise is  just a guessing game.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I added some data to an example so you can see what I've got going on right now.

Comment: Ok, And what is wrong with that result? What result would you want? And why you multiple at the end instead of doing average?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza There isn't anything wrong with it. I just don't know if it's a good way - average would work as well. I haven't been able to find any material on how to weigh multiple columns for an end query so that's kind of what I was looking for. I'm not looking for the "magic" numbers to balance column weights but something to help guide me on making a heuristic. Whenever I find videos explaining search engines I get excited but they never go into any more specific detail than "we use a lot of different factors to sort our results". Point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Weighted Mean.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean